# output daframe as lists in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I downloaded a csv file from a url and save it as dataframe in pyspark. Now I want to print each line of this dataframe as lists. The first 5 rows should look like:

```
[['item', 'item', 'item', 'item'],
  ['item', 'item', 'item'],
  ['item'],
  ['item', 'item', 'item', 'item'],
  ['item',
   'item',
   'item',
   'item']]
```

so far I have done (not showing here my file path):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate()

text_file = sc.textFile("https://.../.../.../.../mydata.csv")
```

I don't know what to do from this part on...I've tried many things nothing works. Can someone help?

Comment: I dont understand, If you download it from some URL, and want just to print it, why using spark? can you be more specific ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your use case? It'll be better if you can share snippet of your input data, making it easier for people to understand your requirement!

Comment: Hi @Dipsy, thanks for your help. My input data is here: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/groceries.csv

Comment: @BennyElgazar, I am learning how to do this in spark, pyspark. I know how to do in Python, but spark is different.

Comment: Not everything needs to be done In Pyspark / Spark. its just a huge overhead you can avoid. 
since you want to interate the rows that means you want to create a spark object and then covert it back back to python lists and iterate it. that means you didn't use spark.

Comment: I know, I am learning pyspark as I'll need to deal with big datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below logic -

```
rdd = sc.textFile("<Your File Path>")
rdd.map(lambda x: x.split('\n')).collect()

[['citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups'],
 ['tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee'],
 ['whole milk'],
 ['pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads'],
 ['other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product']
]
```

Comment: I got the following error:

Comment: What is this error?